# Fresh new project for cocos2d-js 3.7 with Facebook plugin crashes in JNI_OnLoad

Tags: android, facebook, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0, cocos2d-js

Fresh new project for cocos2d-js 3.7 with Facebook plugin crashes in JNI_OnLoad
Any hint on what could be wrong?
I've started with fresh project which runs OK and then integrated the FB plugin manualy based on: https://github.com/chukong/cocos-docs/blob/master/manual/framework/html5/jsb/plugin-x/how-to-use-plugin-x-on-android/en.md

```
D/JniHelper( 7432): JniHelper::setJavaVM(0xb515c280), pthread_self() = -1224978744
--------- beginning of crash
F/libc    ( 7432): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x0 in tid 7432 (li.android.free)
I/DEBUG   (  240): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
I/DEBUG   (  240): Build fingerprint: 'oneplus/bacon/A0001:5.0.2/LRX22G/YNG1TAS2I3:user/release-keys'
I/DEBUG   (  240): Revision: '0'
I/DEBUG   (  240): ABI: 'arm'
I/DEBUG   (  240): pid: 7432, tid: 7432, name: li.android.free  >>> cz.volten.brili.android.free <<<
I/DEBUG   (  240): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x0
I/DEBUG   (  240):     r0 b5151240  r1 03ffffff  r2 00000001  r3 b5151240
I/DEBUG   (  240):     r4 00000043  r5 b5118228  r6 a18ad984  r7 00000000
I/DEBUG   (  240):     r8 b5107800  r9 b50fcc7c  sl beb3be48  fp beb3bc74
I/DEBUG   (  240):     ip a306db2c  sp beb3bc68  lr a18ad9b0  pc 00000000  cpsr 60010010
I/DEBUG   (  240): 
I/DEBUG   (  240): backtrace:
I/DEBUG   (  240):     #00 pc 00000000  <unknown>
I/DEBUG   (  240):     #01 pc 00dc49ac  /data/app/cz.volten.brili.android.free-1/lib/arm/libcocos2djs.so (JNI_OnLoad+40)
I/DEBUG   (  240):     #02 pc 001ceecf  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JavaVMExt::LoadNativeLibrary(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, art::Handle<art::mirror::ClassLoader>, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >*)+1478)
I/DEBUG   (  240):     #03 pc 001f4b8d  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Runtime_nativeLoad(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, _jstring*, _jobject*, _jstring*)+548)
I/DEBUG   (  240):     #04 pc 000777f9  /data/dalvik-cache/arm/system@framework@boot.oat
I/DEBUG   (  240): 
I/DEBUG   (  240): Tombstone written to: /data/tombstones/tombstone_01
W/li.android.free( 7432): type=1701 audit(0.0:173): auid=4294967295 uid=10332 gid=10332 ses=4294967295 subj=u:r:untrusted_app:s0 reason="memory violation" sig=11
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `main.cpp`:

**wrong code (3.5 way):**

```
void cocos_android_app_init (JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz) {
```

**valid code (3.7 way):**

```
void cocos_android_app_init (JNIEnv* env) {
```